# SSE2 optimisation in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, sse

I know in C++ you can use some c++ SSE intrinsic functions to do vector calculations, but not sure if this is possible in latest Delphi compilers.

I have some code like this and they are in the core algorithms that are being called many many times, I would like to speed up this bit.

Any advices would be appreciated.

```
type
  Vector = array [1..3] of Single;
  VectorInt = array [1..3] of Integer;

function TSomeCalculation.getCubePosRound(const xyz: Vector): VectorInt;
begin
  // Self.RESINV and Self.RangeMin are type of Vector     
  Result[1] := Round((xyz[1] - Self.RangeMin[1]) * Self.RESINV[1]);
  Result[2] := Round((xyz[2] - Self.RangeMin[2]) * Self.RESINV[2]);
  Result[3] := Round((xyz[3] - Self.RangeMin[3]) * Self.RESINV[3]);
end;
```

Comment: You can use the `asm` keyword. By the way (as usual) it would be better to operate over an array of input, there are only 3 parallel things here so you'd waste a lane unless you could fill it with the next guy.

Comment: There are no vector arithmetic instructions provided by the compiler. If you want fast vector code, see http://www.dewresearch.com/delphi.

Comment: This is a pretty simply function to write in SSE, why not have a go? Your use of an array here, rather than a record, denies you the chance to use operator overloading, and so denies you a chance of making your arithmetic code clear and readable.

Comment: Can you show me how to write SSE in delphi ? I am not sure I can do it right.

Comment: can I assume parameter xyz: Vector  is 16-byte memory address aligned?

Comment: No you cannot. Without more information, you cannot make any alignment assumptions. The type `Vector` has alignment `4`. But if you declare a `Vector` inside a packed array, it will not be aligned. It gets more complicated when you consider memory managers. The standard Delphi memory manager doesn't offer control over the alignment and I think defaults to 8 byte alignment. You can use a custom MM and gain control over that. Stack allocated variables are not necessarily aligned, in at least some Delphi versions. By and large, Embarcadero don't care about floating point performance.

Comment: To get real speed gain, it would better to make vector type with 4 elements (with dummy entry)  and treat array of 'vectors', not single ones. For 16-byte alignment use SetMinimumBlockAlignment(System.mba16Byte)

Comment: @MBo That controls alignment for the heap allocator. I was wrong when I said that the built in MM does not offer control over that. Thanks. But what about stack allocated values? Or values allocated in records or classes? Unfortunately Delphi offers us no way to specify type alignment so that we can make full use of SSE vectorized operations.

Comment: @David Heffernan Hmm..it could be a problem. I always store my data arrays for SSE treatment in global heap, so I haven't met stack allocation issues yet.

Comment: @MBo If you have arrays of data to work on then that can be viable. But I rather suspect that for the applications that DoctorLai has in mind there will be individual vectors and matrices scattered about here and there. So, proper alignment may not be trivial to arrange.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  yes. majorly vectors scattered everywhere, so it may not be easier to get speed up by using SSE

Comment: BTW, modern processors have smaller penalty for unaligned data instructions than older ones (AFAIK, from Sandy or, probably, Nehalem).

Comment: @DoctorLai Does this function consume more than 10-20% of overall computation time?

Comment: yes, all other similar functions (this one is just a example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick sketch. Note using  of 4-element types.

**Edit.** Changed `movdqu` to `movups` (not essential)

```
type
  Vector = array [0..3] of Single;
  VectorInt = array [0..3] of Integer;
...
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Vec: Vector;
  VecI: VectorInt;
  RESINV: Vector;
  RangeMin: Vector;


procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  vec[0] := 10;
  vec[1] := 12;
  vec[2] := 14;
  vec[3] := 16;
  RangeMin[0] := 4.2;
  RangeMin[1] := 5.2;
  RangeMin[2] := 6.2;
  RangeMin[3] := 7.2;
  RESINV[0] := 0;
  RESINV[1] := 1.1;
  RESINV[2] := 2.2;
  RESINV[3] := 3.3;
  vecI := getCubePosRound(vec);
end;

function Tform1.getCubePosRound(const xyz: Vector): VectorInt;
asm
  movups xmm1, [xyz]   //load 16 bytes unaligned
  movups xmm2, [RangeMin]
  movups xmm3, [RESINV]
  subps xmm1, xmm2  //subtract packed singles
  mulps xmm1, xmm3  //multiply 
  cvtps2dq xmm0, xmm1 //rounded according to MXCSR register
  movdqu [Result], xmm0 //store 16 bytes
end;
```